# npm install -g ionic@latest is not upgrading to ionic 3.0.1

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

After installation i still don't see 3.0.1

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Answer (score 9):

`ionic install -g ionic@latest` installs the latest [*ionic-cli*](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli) package. This is version 2.2.3 currently as is also shown by your output of `ionic info`.

Just run 
`ionic start myapp [template]`

You will notice the current `ionic-angular` version to be 3.x in the project's package.json.

Comment: Ionic CLI remains to v2 even if you follow this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade2 it break everything i think its safer to stick to v2 :)

Comment: Or just use this `ionic start myfirstapp blank --v2` @SunilKumar